# USA Visa Schedule for Spouse Only

Tags: visas, usa

My wife and I applied for US Visa in March 2019.  For that, we filed DS-160 on https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/, created profile on https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/?language=English&country=India, and scheduled interview.  Unfortunately, we got rejected.
Now, I am planning to have only my wife appear for visa interview.  But, I am not sure how can I schedule interview just for her.  I filed new DS-160, and got new application ID.  But, when I try to schedule interview using profile I already created, it is not allowing me to schedule it for her.  I cannot remove my information.  If I keep my information, then at the end it is asking me to provide payment receipt number for both of us.
I just want to pay for my wife's visa interview at bank and provide that receipt number on the profile I created previously.  Can someone please help me with this?  If I leave my payment receipt number blank and only put my wife's payment receipt number, will it allow me to schedule it?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.